# i want to search file for three strings and type 'defect' only if those both strings are present

Tags: python-2.7

I have a txt file with three debug signature present on them.

```
x = 'task cocaLc Requested reboot'
y = 'memPartFree'
z = 'memPartAlloc'

import re
f = open('testfile.txt','r')
searchstrings = ('task cocaLc Requested reboot', 'memPartFree',     'memPartAlloc')
for line in f():
    for word in searchstrings:
        if any (s in line for s in searchstrings):
            print 'defect'
```

I want to create a short script to scan through the file and print 'defect' only if all these three strings are present.
I was trying creating with different ways, but unable to meet the requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there is a small error on line 4 of the example code. `f` is not callable, and thus you shouldn't be using parenthesis next to it.

If you have a file with the following in it:

```
task cocaLc Requested reboot
memPartFree
memPartAlloc
```

It will print out "defect" 9 times because you're checking once for each line, and once for each search string. So three lines, times three search strings is 9.

The `any()` function will return `True` **any** time the file contains at least one of the defined search strings. Thus, this code will print out "defect" once for each line, multiplied by the number of search strings you've defined.

To resolve this, the program will need to know if/when any of the particular search strings have been detected. You might do something like this:

```
f = open('testfile.txt','r')

searchstrings = ['task cocaLc Requested reboot', 'memPartFree', 'memPartAlloc']
detections = [False, False, False]

for line in f:
    for i in range(0, len(searchstrings)):
        if searchstrings[i] in line: #loop through searchstrings using index numbers
            detections[i] = True
            break    #break out of the loop since the word has been detected

if all(detections): #if every search string was detected, every value in detections should be true
    print "defect"
```

In this code, we loop through the lines and the search strings, but the `detection` variable serves to tell us which search strings have been detected in the file. Thus, if `all` elements in that list are true, that means all of the search strings have been detected in the file.